# Buscar substring en directorio de ficheros

Tags: python

estoy intentando sacar el fichero que contenga un día en especifico de un directorio de ficheros. Supongamos que tengo una carpeta con ficheros excel

`lista=['f1.xlsx','f2.xlsx','f3.xlsx']`

```
def some():
   files=os.listdir(r'path')



    for file in files:

    day='23'

    if file.startswith('~$'):
        files.remove(file)
    if day in file:
        archivo=os.path.join(r'path',file)
        print(archivo)

 some()
```

Comment: ¿Por que esta es una pregunta de Pandas? ¿falta código?

Comment: tras encontrar el fichero que quiero me gustaría leer ese fichero con un pd.read_excel

Comment: pues solo pon eso... quitando el `return` de la linea `return print(file)` y agregando `archivo = pd.read_excel(file)`  y luego `print(archivo)` debería hacer el trabajo

Comment: Lo anterior tomando en cuenta que los archivos `.xlsx` estan en la misma carpeta del archivo python, si no tendras que hacer un `os.path.join(PATH,file)` donde `PATH` es el directorio que pasaste por `os.listdir()`

Comment: la cosa es que "in" no me devuelve nada.

Comment: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Comment: al probar el codigo que tienes me funciona bien con un archivo que contenga "23" en su nombre, no sera que estas pasando "files" en vez de "file" al pd.read_excel()?

Comment: he editado el código. Esoty cometiendo algún error tonto

Comment: cambia files del os.path.join() por el string que pasate en el os.listdir()

Comment: Correcto. Y esto me respetará que por ejemplo si hay dos ficheros "1.xlsx" y "11.xlsx" y especifico en day=11 me lea el del 11 o me leerá el del 1 por estar el primero en la lista?

Comment: hará una búsqueda exacta del substring?

Comment: tomara la primera instancia que contenga "11" en su nombre no "1" en caso de que tengas un archivo "f111" y "f11" podrias aislar con regex la "f" o string antes de los numeros y extraer solo el numero, eso sera una busqueda mas exacta

Comment: Ok. Una última cuestión. Cómo podría obtener el path de ese file resultante con os?   archivo=os.path.join(r'\path',file) al hacer el print no hace nada

Comment: print a donde? en todo caso revisa minuciosamente el path que pasaste en os.listdir() y el nombre del archivo xlsx, sin mas información de la carpeta no puedo ayudar mucho

Comment: He editado la cuestión. No me hace el print del path.

Comment: Repito, revisa bien el path porque puede que estes pasando algo que no exista, os.path.join() va a unir strings asi el archivo o carpeta no existan porque simplemente es una utilidad para facilitar la búsqueda de archivos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya con lo discutido en los comentarios de esta pregunta, se resolvieron gran parte del problema, asi que planteo la solución que probé y funcionó, este codigo es tomando en cuenta que se conoce la posición del la carpeta contenedora del archivo xlsx y el nombre del archivo en cuestión:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
def some():
    path = "carpeta" #esta carpeta es una subparpeta de la ubicación donde se encuentra el archivo python
    files=os.listdir(path)
  

    conteo_files=0
    for file in files:

        day='23'

        if file.startswith('~$'):
            files.remove(file)
        if day in file:
            archivo = os.path.join(path,file)
            print(archivo)
            df = pd.read_excel(archivo)
            print(df)
            

some()
```

al ejecutar este codigo obtengo como resultado:

```
carpeta\ea_23122021.xlsx
   a  b  c
0  1  4  5
1  2  3  6
>>>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona

Comment: Que bueno volverte a ver por acá ^_^